# select inside insert with more data to be inserted

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a problem with select inside insert statements.
I've take a look at the questions similar to this but still the query is not working.

first, I'm working with MySQL version 5.6.24 with engine InnoDB, and I'm trying to insert this row:

```
    INSERT INTO form (SELECT course_name FROM course WHERE course_id ='1' ), '123456','5','3','6','1','3','6','1','2','5','6','1','4','1','2','3','good','not bad','bad')
```

I want the first column to be retrieved (which is only one value), but not the other.
I've tried many syntax formats, with VALUES, with semicolon, with more parentheses, etc... but non work. Here is the error:

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '123456','5','3','6','1','3','6','1','2','5','6','1','4','1','2','3','good','no' at line 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [INSERT-SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO form
SELECT course_name, '123456','5','3','6','1','3','6','1','2','5','6','1','4','1','2','3','good','not bad','bad'
FROM course
WHERE course_id = '1'
```